# Maven clean install doesn't reflect on submodules

Tags: maven-3

I have created one `pom.xml` with packaging POM which has all submodules to be build.

Assume that pom has 4 modules: `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`.
When I try to run the Module A separately, the latest changes has been reflected. When I try to run the pom which has been packaged as POM with `mvn clean install`, I am not able to run it with latest changes in all modules of POM.

Comment: If you have declared your submodules properly there is nothing that can hide changes. can you provide your pom and the directories hierarchy

Comment: <modules>
   <module>../A</module>
   <module>../B</module>
   <module>../C</module>
   <module>../D</module>
  </modules>  Consider that i am running module B separately with clean install,then the latest changes in POM is reflecting. If i try to run the above illustrated project POM,then the latest changes been neglected

Comment: I didn't get it, you are saying changes in pom, you mean that you make changes in pom like dependencie, plugins ... or you mean changes in the module source code ? do you have inherentence in your pom declaration <parent>..?

Answer (score 0):

example of parent pom with child modules is here http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-parent.html  make sure you children/modules do not have a version in, they will get that from the parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. You have to include your sub-modules in the parent pom.

Parent.pom (say A)

<modules>B</modules>
<modules>C</modules>
<modules>D</modules>

2. In the child pom , you need to specify the parent.

B.pom
    <parent>
        <groupId>groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>version</version>
    </parent>
C.pom
     <parent>
        <groupId>groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>version</version>
    </parent>
```